# For each save (update) hibernate envers creating revisions either changed in table or not

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

In my client server application, I am using JavaFx as client and Java hibernate as server to db connection.

**Problem**

I have one save button and for each click on button, envers creates one revision, whether there is no change in table values.
Basically it is not checking old data to new data, just creating revisions.

Here is my bean code

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "DOMAIN")
public class Domain implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long domainId;
private String domainName;
private String dataType;
private Long valueSize;
private Long valuePrecision;
private Long valueScale;
private String valueRangeLow;
private String valueRangeHigh;
private String description;
private String comments;
private Date effectiveStartDate;
private Date effectiveEndDate;
private String status;

public Domain() {
}

public Domain(Long domainId, String domainName, String dataType,
        Date effectiveStartDate, Date effectiveEndDate, String status) {
    this.domainId = domainId;
    this.domainName = domainName;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
    this.effectiveEndDate = effectiveEndDate;
    this.status = status;
}

public Domain(Long domainId, String domainName, String dataType,
        Long valueSize, Long valuePrecision,
        Long valueScale, String valueRangeLow, String valueRangeHigh,
        String description, String comments, Date effectiveStartDate,
        Date effectiveEndDate, String status) {
    this.domainId = domainId;
    this.domainName = domainName;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.valueSize = valueSize;
    this.valuePrecision = valuePrecision;
    this.valueScale = valueScale;
    this.valueRangeLow = valueRangeLow;
    this.valueRangeHigh = valueRangeHigh;
    this.description = description;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
    this.effectiveEndDate = effectiveEndDate;
    this.status = status;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "DOMAIN_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name="DOMAIN_SEQ", sequenceName="DOMAIN_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "DOMAIN_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Long getDomainId() {
    return this.domainId;
}

public void setDomainId(Long domainId) {
    this.domainId = domainId;
}

@Column(name = "DOMAIN_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getDomainName() {
    return this.domainName;
}

public void setDomainName(String domainName) {
    this.domainName = domainName;
}

@Column(name = "DATA_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getDataType() {
    return this.dataType;
}

public void setDataType(String dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_SIZE", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Long getValueSize() {
    return this.valueSize;
}

public void setValueSize(Long valueSize) {
    this.valueSize = valueSize;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_PRECISION", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Long getValuePrecision() {
    return this.valuePrecision;
}

public void setValuePrecision(Long valuePrecision) {
    this.valuePrecision = valuePrecision;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_SCALE", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Long getValueScale() {
    return this.valueScale;
}

public void setValueScale(Long valueScale) {
    this.valueScale = valueScale;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_RANGE_LOW", length = 50)
public String getValueRangeLow() {
    return this.valueRangeLow;
}

public void setValueRangeLow(String valueRangeLow) {
    this.valueRangeLow = valueRangeLow;
}

@Column(name = "VALUE_RANGE_HIGH", length = 50)
public String getValueRangeHigh() {
    return this.valueRangeHigh;
}

public void setValueRangeHigh(String valueRangeHigh) {
    this.valueRangeHigh = valueRangeHigh;
}

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 200)
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name = "COMMENTS")
public String getComments() {
    return this.comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_START_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
public Date getEffectiveStartDate() {
    return this.effectiveStartDate;
}

public void setEffectiveStartDate(Date effectiveStartDate) {
    this.effectiveStartDate = effectiveStartDate;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "EFFECTIVE_END_DATE", nullable = false, length = 7)
public Date getEffectiveEndDate() {
    return this.effectiveEndDate;
}

public void setEffectiveEndDate(Date effectiveEndDate) {
    this.effectiveEndDate = effectiveEndDate;
}

@Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

Problem is only with client server application.

With normal standalone program it is working fine.

Could anyone help me? I stuck at this point. Am i missing any jars or anything else?
If you need more clarification about question then please tell me.

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
public long saveDomainFromJson(String domainJsonData) throws Exception {
    long domainId = 0;
    try {
        // here I am setting data to bean, getting from client side
        Domain domain = getDomainFromJson(domainJsonData);           

        Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        domainId  = session.saveOrUpdate(domain);

        tx.commit();
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return domainId;
}
```

**Json Data**

```
{
  "DOMAIN_ID":36,
  "DOMAIN_NAME":"Test_Type",
  "DOMAIN_DATA_TYPE":"STRING",
  "DOMAIN_EFF_START_DATE":"2016-11-08",
  "DOMAIN_EFF_END_DATE":"2099-12-31",
  "DOMAIN_STATUS":"Draft",
  "DOMAIN_DESCRIPTION":"Object Type: Added for testing purpose"
}
```

Comment: Are the date values being set by the client every time a change is made by chance?

Comment: If you could include your server-side code that manipulates the entity and updates the state, that'd help too.

Comment: Yes, client can set date and I am setting the same date as previous.. AND, I have included the server side code here, you can take a look

Comment: At first I thought this might have been an issue with the `TemporalType.DATE` and Envers not respecting that, but that isn't the case.  My only conclusion based on what you've shown is that some field's value differs between what the database has and what the client sends.  Can you show evidence that isn't the case here?  What version of Hibernate & Hibernate Envers are you using too, please?

Comment: Earlier I thought the same but db field value is same as client value, I have checked multiple times. And I am using 'hibernate-envers-5.2.4' with the same 'hibernate jars version'. Here for each save button clicked it is running the insert query in both REVINFO and _Aud table without checking changes(as I think its not checking). Not getting where is the problem, Is there required any extra jars

Comment: Can you post your JSON string when you click your save button?  I suspect that your JSON stream may not include the identifier perhaps?

Comment: Json data added too, take a look with this, rest values in this can have null, and all properties values are matching with their previous values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I didn't see this soon, but the problem is your call to `session#save`.  From the javadocs for `Session` [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html), you'll notice the following passage:

> save() and persist() result in an SQL INSERT, delete() in an SQL DELETE and update() or merge() in an SQL UPDATE. Changes to persistent instances are detected at flush time and also result in an SQL UPDATE. saveOrUpdate() and replicate() result in either an INSERT or an UPDATE.

So you basically want to use `session#saveOrUpdate` so that you get both insert and update semantics based on the state of your entity.

Since `session#save` is generating a new `INSERT` operation, Envers will always create a new revision for that case regardless.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation, Now I tried with **session#saveOrUpdate** but still envers is creating new revision for every click, I am just updating data, not inserting new data.

Comment: When you say _updating_, is the data actually changing with the clicks?

Comment: I got the problem, Thanks for your docs reference **Naros**. So Instead of **session#saveOrUpdate** , I had to use **session#merge**. Now envers is compairing every time and if it find changes then only creating revision, Now application is working fine.. voillaaa

Comment: @V.Dev There should be no difference between `saveOrUpdate` and `merge` afaik, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: Just tested doing something like `Domain domain = session.find( Domain.class, domainId )` followed by a simple call to `session.save( domain )` and no revision was created.  So it must be something in how you're sending the data or manipulating it which you haven't specified.  It doesn't matter whether I call `save`, `saveOrUpdate`, `update`, or `merge`, they all work the same.

Comment: Yes @Naros, as I mentioned in question, that envers things is working fine with standalone application whether I call 'save', 'saveOrUpdate', 'update', or 'merge', same as u tried. But I had a problem with client server application, and in this only merge is working. not getting properly but as I am getting, envers probably looks in session, in saveOrUpdate **if the object is versioned (by a <version> or <timestamp>), and the version property value is the same value assigned to a newly instantiated object, save() it** (as mentioned in docs), that is not in case of **merge**

Comment: I still don't understand how being a client/server app vs a standalone makes a difference here.  My point is this entire post is misleading as there are missing details and it seems to portray there is a bug here and I surmise that is in your implementation which I'd like to try help solve but can't without clearer details.